# How can I confirm if sendmail is (or is not) converting a message from 8 to 7 bits?

Tags: email-server, sendmail

As is eluded to in a few other recent posts of mine, I suspect that sendmail is attempting to convert a message from 8 to 7 bits.  How can I confirm if it's doing this? Is this something that would be caught with elevated debug logging? I didn't see a specific debug log level documented that captures this information.

Comment: You mean 8 bit like in UTF8 ?

Comment: @yagmoth555 i think so but with a catch... the incoming mime source doesn't specify a char set so I'm not 100% certain it's UTF8

Comment: By default it should be in UTF-8, as in programmation UTF-8 is easy to support (unsigned char). To test setup a french qwerty keyboard, like french canada, which is near usa for the letter, and send a mail with the special letter in it and test the result. Like é è ç, etc..